# Mapping Salesforce Coordinates Field?

Tags: visualforce, custom-field

Any direct bolt on appexchange apps or other internal salesforce solutions to take the new Salesforce Coordinates field types to automatically visualize a map based the latitude and longitude entered in that Coordinates field?

I am just looking to render those coordinates onto a VF section on the page layout or something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the map component is needed on a Lightning record page, `lightning-map` can be used in a generic LWC component by specifying the object's `Geolocation` field names as property fields.

Then call wire method `getRecord` to retrieve the coordinate field values to construct the map markers.

Here's a sample code to get you started.

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-map if:true={mapMarkers}
        map-markers={mapMarkers}
        zoom-level="15"
    >
    </lightning-map>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement,api, wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class LwcMapByCoords extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @api latField;
    @api lonField;

    @api 
    get fields() {
        if(this.latField && this.lonField){
            return [
                this.objectApiName+'.'+ this.latField,
                this.objectApiName+'.'+ this.lonField
            ];
        }
    }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: '$fields'})
    record;

    get mapMarkers() {
        let markers = null;
        if(this.record.data && 
            this.record.data.fields[this.lonField].value && 
            this.record.data.fields[this.latField].value){

            let lat = this.record.data.fields[this.latField].value;
            let lon = this.record.data.fields[this.lonField].value;
            markers = [
                {
                    location: {
                        Latitude: lat,
                        Longitude: lon
                    },
                },
            ];
        }
        return markers;
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="latField" label="Latitude Field Name" type="String" default="Geolocation__Latitude__s"/>
            <property name="lonField" label="Longitude Field Name" type="String" default="Geolocation__Longitude__s" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

For reference [lightning-map documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation)

> **Usage Considerations** 
> lightning-map uses the Google Maps Platform and is bound to its terms of service. The use of Google Maps Platform is prohibited in specific territories based on IP addresses. For more information, see [Google Maps Platform Prohibited Territories](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories). lightning-map is not supported in these territories and does not load correctly when accessed from the IP addresses associated with these territories. Users in these territories can continue to use Google Maps directly as detailed at [Google Maps Platform Coverage Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/coverage).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many features you need, there are a variety of options from the AppExchange that vary in price:

[Geopointe](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZHeEAM)

[Google Maps for Salesforce by Pexys](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001tka6EAA)

[neoMapper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008afJ7EAI)

[Customer Compass](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4SQwEAN)

I haven't used any of them myself, but I've heard good things about each from other Salesforce users.